# How do I display a control over a video that is playing in my winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, transparent

I was just wondering how to display a transparent control over a playing video in c#, winforms application. In my application, I am playing a video in my winform, and I want to display some information-by adding a label or picturebox. I was wondering how to make the controls transparent, so that you could see the playing video, while seeing some labels and pictureboxes on top of it.

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
        label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        label1.ForeColor = Color.White;
```

Comment: Well, that wouldnt work in my situation :( I am trying to make the label transparent over a video, not the window.. When i make the label transparent, it does come over the video, but some of the control is visible around the label:( Thanks for your amazingly fast reply though